# GUI login system not react while clicking OK button

Tags: java, swing

hope you are ok this evening.

I have a problem with GUI login system. I was able to create frame with labels and fields to input user name and password, however when I'm clicking the OK button it doesn't react to my action and not changing color what I like.
Can you take a look please ?

```
public class LoginPanel  extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;                                                   // frame
    static JTextField userField;                                    // field to get user name
    JLabel userLabel;                                               // using for printing label on frame
    static JPasswordField passwordField;                            // field where you put your passowrd
    JButton loginButton;                                            // add OK button below login

    public LoginPanel () {
        super();
        frame = new JFrame ("Login");                               // initial frame, add title
        frame.setSize(500, 500);                                    // frame size
        frame.setLocation(300, 200);                                // set where program window should start
        frame.setLayout(null);                                      // set layout; you can use (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.LEFT));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       // closing the program by clicking X

        userLabel = new JLabel("enter user name label");            // create Label next to the user field
        userLabel.setLocation(10, 10);                              // set location where label will start to appear
        userLabel.setSize (userLabel.getPreferredSize());           //
        frame.add(userLabel);                                       // add userLabel to the frame

        userField = new JTextField ();                              // initial text field for user name
        userField.setColumns(25);
        userField.setSize(userField.getPreferredSize());            // set text field size                          // 
        userField.setLocation(150, 10);                             // set where text field will apear on frame;
        userField.setToolTipText("enter user name");                // when you move the mouse on the field, you will get a hint
        frame.add(userField);                                       // add userfield to the frame

        userLabel = new JLabel("enter password label");             // create Label next to the password field
        userLabel.setLocation(10, 40);                              // set location where label will start to appear
        userLabel.setSize (userLabel.getPreferredSize());           //
        frame.add(userLabel);                                       // add label to the frame

        passwordField = new JPasswordField ();                      // add password field next to the label
        passwordField.setColumns(25);                               // 
        passwordField.setSize(userField.getPreferredSize());        // set text field size          
        passwordField.setLocation(150, 40);                         // set location where password field will apear
        passwordField.setToolTipText("enter password");             // when you move the mouse on the field, you will get a hint
        frame.add(passwordField);                                   // add password field to the frame

        loginButton = new JButton("OK");                            // add OK button
        loginButton.setSize(loginButton.getPreferredSize());        // 
        loginButton.setLocation(150, 80);                           // set where ok button appears
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);                        // add action listener to the button when click to the button then method actionPerformed
        frame.add(loginButton);                                     // add button to the frame

        frame.setVisible(true);                                     // frame visibility; ALWAYS at the end, because will not show entire content of frame


    }                                                               // end of Login Panel code

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object source = e.getSource();
        if(passwordField.equals("1234") && (userField.equals("tomek"))) {
setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
    else {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    }   
    public static void main (String [] args) {                      // adding at the end as every program need to have main method
        new LoginPanel();                                           // run method LoginPanel
}
```

Comment: Did you try keeping SOP in `actionPerformed` method to know whether it's getting called?

Comment: I hope this `passwordField.equals("1234")` should be like `passwordField.getText().equals("1234")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```java
 @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (new String(passwordField.getPassword()).equals("1234") && (userField.getText()
        .equals("tomek"))) {
      frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
      frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
  }
```

- you should call setBackground on the `ContentPane` of the `JFrame` not on the actual panel as your are not using it
- you should compare your `JTextField` and `JPasswordField` contents not the components to the username `tomek` and password `1234`